# update multiple records in mysql database from php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, database

In the php code below, if you type something into the top input box and click the button the mysql database is updated.  I would like to do the same thing with the form below that has multiple boxes (the actual form will have more than two).

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>
function showList(){
var i=0;
var rankNum;
rankNum = 1;
var vfundsym;
while (i<=5)
{
alert(rankNum + " " + document.getElementById("o" + (i+1)).value);
i++;
rankNum++;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="getuser3.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id='fundAge' name="fundAge" size="7" maxlength="7" />
<input  style="visibility: visible" id="addFundtoDB" type="submit" value="Update Database" />
</form>

<p>The form above updates one record in the database. How can I loop through the form below and update each record?</p>

<form name="orderedlist" action="getuser3.php" method="post">
<form>
<table>
<tr><td><textarea class="orderedlist" name="p1" id="o1"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea class="orderedlist" name="p2" id="o2"></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="run SHOWLIST function" onclick="showList()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The getuser3.php code is below.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("devtechw_ajax_demo", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Age=('$_POST[fundAge]')
WHERE ID='2'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your script as it is, is vulnerable to tampering via SQL injection attacks.  You must, at a minimum, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_POST['fundAge']`.  `$fundage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fundAge']);` Then use `$fundAge` in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I've removed your username/password from the code above, but you should probably change them on your server anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Neglecting the gaping wide-open SQL injection hole you've got, you can update multiple fields in a single record like this:

```
UPDATE sometable
SET field1=value1, field2=value2, field3=etc...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I will add the SQL injection in the real version after I get the test version working. Sorry, I screwed up and forgot to mention the the number of "rows" varies dynamically, so I don't think I can use: `code`SET field1=value1, field2=value2, field3=etc...`code`  I need to iterate through the rows until I reach the end @Milap

Comment: UPDATE is a set based operation, you can and should use it to update a set (multiple) records.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SQL query as 

`$sql="UPDATE user SET Age='".$_POST[fundAge]."' WHERE ID='2'";

mysql_query($sql);`


I guess this will do the trick